# Latest version of jQuery that works in Salesforce Lightning with LockerService?

Tags: lightning, jquery, locker-service

I'd like to know what is the most recent versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI that works with Salesforce Lightning with LockerService on?

Comment: We've been continuously using jQuery internally, including the latest 3.3.1, with success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any version of jQuery at or above version 2.2.4 should work without any problems. That said, keep in mind that the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html) advises against using DOM manipulation libraries:

> In the Lightning approach, the model and the view are decoupled: your code doesn’t have to reach into the DOM. This leads to more robust and more maintainable code. Avoiding direct DOM manipulation is a best practice in the Lightning Component Framework (like in most modern frameworks), and you might just discover that you no longer need your DOM manipulation library.

---

> You may also want to reconsider the use of UI libraries like Bootstrap and jQuery UI. Although these libraries provide useful components, they have their own UI identity that can clash with the Lightning Experience identity. The [Base Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_overview.htm) and the [Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) offer similar capabilities while providing a consistent user experience.

Comment: The documentation doe not advise against the use of jQuery... the blog post you include by the esteemed Christophe Coenraets advises that the many features available in LEX make the use of jQuery less relevant. An important distinction so we don't confuse folks. ;)